# Display hint on jquery ui autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to display  hint `onfocus` using jquery ui autocomplete, i.e. when the user focuses on the input, it should dropdown with a text saying "search something" 
Can you help please? thanks

Comment: What's the code you're working with? Try putting together a demo at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so's we can see what you've tried, or are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like a tool tip

Try [yahoo tooltip](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/container/tooltip/)

Also try putting the `title` attribute in the input textbox of your search

```
<input type='text' title='Search something' name='txtSearch'>
```

Answer (score 5):

Is it much better to put your hint on an [HTML5 placeholder](http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/input-placeholder.html)?

```
 placeholder="Search Something"
```